# SQL: Calculating the day over day repeat user percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `events` table that has an `user_id` and `created_at` columns.

What I'd like to figure out is the percentage of users having day-over-day repeat entries in the `events` table.

So, if day `d1` has `user_id`s `[a,b,c]`, and day `d2` has `user_id`s `[b,d,e]`, then `b` is the only repeat `user_id` of the three (from `d1`), and there is 33% overlap between `d1` and `d2`.

I'd like to be able to extend this for an arbitrary number of days.

The schema in question:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  events_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, user_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
, created_at datetime NOT NULL
);
```

This is a large table, having ~25MM rows per day, with ~4.5MM distinct `user_id`s per day.

Example data set:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| user_id |     created_at      |
+---------+---------------------+
| bob     | 2014-12-02 11:11:11 |
| sally   | 2014-12-02 12:12:11 |
| zed     | 2014-12-02 12:22:11 |
|         | ...                 |
| chris   | 2014-12-03 11:13:11 |
| mark    | 2014-12-03 11:11:13 |
| zed     | 2014-12-03 11:11:33 |
|         | ...                 |
| sydney  | 2014-12-04 11:14:11 |
| zed     | 2014-12-04 11:44:11 |
| chris   | 2014-12-04 11:44:11 |
|         | ...                 |
| sydney  | 2014-12-05 11:15:11 |
| zed     | 2014-12-05 11:55:11 |
| chris   | 2014-12-05 11:55:15 |
| sandy   | 2014-12-05 11:55:51 |
| sydney  | 2014-12-05 11:55:55 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+------------+---------------------------+
|    day     | returning_user_percentage |
+------------+---------------------------+
| 2014-12-02 | NULL                      |
| 2014-12-03 | 33                        |
| 2014-12-04 | 66                        |
| 2014-12-05 | 75                        |
+------------+---------------------------+
```

Additionally, and quite probably far more simple, part 2:  I'd like to know how many new users there are each day, where "new" means the `user_id` has not previously been seen.

Comment: The question is not entirely clear, and either way it would be essential to know whether users can have multiple events per day. A ***table definition*** would clarify that (among other things).

Comment: Updated question with much more detail.  Thanks.

Comment: (1) I believe that is what my answer does; (2) You should stick to one question in a question.  If you want to ask about new customers, ask another question.

Comment: So there can be any number of entries for the same user for a single day? How do you calculate **60 %** in the last line exactly? **100 %** of users from 12-04 appear 12-05, **75 %** of the users 12-05 already appeared 12-04 and **80 %** of the *entries* are with users that appeared the previous day. Either way, it doesn't add up for me.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, good catch, and my apologies:  75% is correct, and I've updated accordingly.  3 of the 4 user_ids from 12-04 were seen on 12-05.  And yes:  There can be multiple entries for the same user for a single day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to updated question:

*"Calculate for every day the percentage of distinct users that have entries for the previous day as well."*

```
WITH e AS (SELECT created_at::date, user_id AS day FROM events GROUP BY 1, 2)
SELECT e.day
     , round(100.0 * count(e1.user_id) / count(*), 2) AS pct_repeat_user
FROM   e
LEFT   JOIN e e1 ON e1.user_id = e.user_id
                AND e1.day = e.day - 1
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Returns your desired result - but `0` instead of `NULL` for the first day, which seems more correct to me.

#### Explain

- Your "date" is actually a [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) (not "datetime"). To get unique users **per day**, I cast to `date` and group users in  CTE `u`. This is **crucial** or you get nonsensical results from cross-joining duplicate users on one day with duplicate users on the previous day.
- Building on that, `LEFT JOIN` to the previous day. Count users that can be found "yesterday" as well and divide by the number of users "today". Multiply by `100.0` to coerce the number to `numeric` before dividing and use `round()` to get your desired number of fractional digits.
- Since `day` is data type `date` now you can simply subtract an `integer` 1 from it to get "yesterday.
- Be aware that a "day" is also defined by the time zone - if you should have data from multiple time zones. Does not act up as long as you just store `timestamp`, but there may be an inherent error in your data. Details:

  - [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/996a4/6)

#### DB design

For millions of rows and multiple entries per user I would urgently advice to create a separate `users` table and reference it to reduce disk space and improve performance:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, username text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE events (
  events_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, user_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES users
, created_at timestamp NOT NULL
);
```

This would also instrumental to speed up a number or other queries.

Comment: Thanks Erwin.  In your first query, shouldn't the `pct_repeat_user` subquery be bounded by day, else I'll get a distinct count of all `user_id`s in the table.  In the second query, unfortunately, I do not have a `users` table that I can join against.  I'm still playing with your query to see if it gives the results I want.

Comment: @findchris: Consider the new answer for your clarified question.

Comment: This looks good @Erwin.  Thank you.  I had thought I'd have to use something more complicated, such as `RANK` and `LAG`, but your solution is nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `created_at` is a date with no time component:

```
select e.created_at,
       avg(case when eprev.user_id is not null then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as overlap
from events e left join
     events eprev
     on e.created_at = eprev.created_at + interval '1' day and e.user_id = eprev.user_id
group by e.created_at
```

Comment: This doesn't count a "percentage of users having day-over-day repeat entries" so much as the percentage of "day-over-day repeat entries" per day - which is something completely different. Quite possible that the OP really wants that (the overlap he mentions points that way), but he stated differently.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  See updated question above.

Comment: If you want values from 0 to 100, change `1.0` to `100.0`.